# Get rows with checked boxes in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to find the rows with a checked box and then grab a column value form that row. Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    var chckbox = $(this).find('.checkItem');
    if (chckbox.checked) {  
    ids.push($(this).find(".id").html());
    }
});
```

The problem right now is it never gets inside the if statement. The class names are all correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    var chckbox = $(this).find('.checkItem');
    if (chckbox.prop('checked')) {  
        ids.push($(this).find(".id").html());
    }
});
```

[jQuery .prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: should use `prop` instead of `attr`.  Attr is supposed to be for values that don't change.

Comment: Great stuff, glad I (or we!) could help. If it has been super-helpful, please feel free to mark this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

It would also work if you do it this way:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr .checkItem:checked').each(function () {
    ids.push($(this).closest('tr').find(".id").html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the array of IDs all in one go:

```
var ids = $('#myTable .checkItem:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').html();
}).get();
```

Note the use of `.map` rather than a `push` inside a `.each` loop.

`.map` is usually the function you want to use if you have an array of elements and want to retrieve some value from each of them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
  var chckbox = $(this).find('.checkItem:checked');
  if (chckbox.length) {  
    ids.push($(this).find(".id").html());
  }
});
```